# Como alterar valor de um array de objetos?

Tags: javascript

Preciso multiplicar a idade de cada usuário por 2 e alterá-la em cada objeto. Como faço para alterar o valor?

```js
const usuarios = [
    { nome: 'Diego', idade: 23, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
    { nome: 'Gabriel', idade: 15, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
    { nome: 'Lucas', idade: 30, empresa: 'Facebook' },
];
```

```js
for (let usuario of usuarios) {
    const multiplicarIdade = usuario.idade * 2
}
```

```js
console.log(usuarios)
```

Resultado esperado:

```js
// Resultado:
[
 { nome: 'Diego', idade: 46, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
 { nome: 'Gabriel', idade: 30, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
]
```

Comment: Então, a proposta original era multiplicar a idade de cada usuário por 2 e retornar por fim a idade dos usuários menores de 50. Usei a dica de todos, porém como o `ḿap` cria a cópia do original, mas com novos valores, dentro desse cenário ficou mais interessante usá-la.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rapaz acredito que a maneira mais fácil de resolver isso é com um [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), por exemplo :

```
     const novosUsuarios = usuarios.map(u => ({ ...u, idade: u.idade * 2 }));
     console.log(novosUsuarios);
```

fiz um [exemplo](https://playcode.io/675591/) rodando, se você quiser conferir

Answer (score 3):

Você *quase* acertou, só faltou colocar o resultado da multiplicação na propriedade `idade`:

```js
const usuarios = [
    { nome: 'Diego', idade: 23, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
    { nome: 'Gabriel', idade: 15, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
    { nome: 'Lucas', idade: 30, empresa: 'Facebook' },
];
for (let usuario of usuarios) {
    usuario.idade *= 2; // <--- aqui
}
console.log(usuarios);
```

No caso, `usuario.idade *= 2` é o mesmo que fazer `usuario.idade = usuario.idade * 2`. Ou seja, eu altero o valor da idade, que passa a ser o dobro do valor original.

Uma das respostas sugeriu usar `map`, o que também funciona. A diferença é que `map` retorna **outro** array com os valores modificados. Então as soluções não são equivalentes, e para decidir qual usar vai depender do que você precisa. Se quer alterar os próprios valores do array, use o *loop* acima. Se quer manter os valores originais e criar uma cópia com os valores modificados, use `map`.

Answer (score 3):

A maneira mais simples é assim:

```js
const usuarios = [
    { nome: 'Diego', idade: 23, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
    { nome: 'Gabriel', idade: 15, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
    { nome: 'Lucas', idade: 30, empresa: 'Facebook' },
];

usuarios.forEach(usuario => usuario.idade = usuario.idade * 2);

console.log(usuarios);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz com um loop passando por toda a lista, veja se funciona e se consegue entender como funciona

```
const usuarios = [
    { nome: 'Diego', idade: 23, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
    { nome: 'Gabriel', idade: 15, empresa: 'Rocketseat' },
    { nome: 'Lucas', idade: 30, empresa: 'Facebook' },
];

for (i = 0; i < usuarios.length; i++) {
    var aux = usuarios[i]['idade'] * 2;
    usuarios[i]['idade'] = aux;
}
```